# Calling outer class' syncronized method from inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, synchronized

I have a program that looks in essence like this

```
class Outer {
    class Inner implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Which lock does `Inner.run()` acquire when it is calling `doSomething()`?  Is it identical to `synchronized(Inner.this)` or `synchronized(Outer.this)`?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `synchronized` has nothing to do with the callsite.

Comment: `Inner.this` and `Outer.this` aren't valid pieces of code in Java.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 They are. They allow you to be specific about enclosing instances, for inner classes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As I pretty much never use non-static inner class I didn't know about that!

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Nitpick, you pretty much never use non-static _nested_ classes. _Inner_ classes refer to non-static nested classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receiver for the invocation of `doSomething()` within `run()` is `Outer.this`. The `synchronized` will therefore lock the monitor on the object referenced by that expression.

On [computing the target reference in a method invocation expression](http://Compute%20Target%20Reference%20(If%20Necessary)), the JLS says

> Otherwise, let `T` be the enclosing type declaration of which the
>   method is a member, and let `n` be an integer such that `T` is the `n'th`
>   lexically enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration
>   immediately contains the method invocation. The target reference is
>   the `n'th` lexically enclosing instance of this.

`T` here is `Outer`, since that's the class that declares it. `n` is 1, as `Outer` is the immediately enclosing type declaration of `Inner`. The target reference is therefore the 1'th lexically enclosing instance of `this`, ie. `Outer.this`.

[Concerning `synchronized` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6), the JLS says

> For an instance method, the monitor associated with `this` (the object
>   for which the method was invoked) is used.